# I need update the spinner text in another textview

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-spinner

I have an spinner in the adapter to get the quantity of the food item. Now, I want to get the spinner text and multiply it with the price to get the total price. How should I do that?

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: View_Holder, position: Int) {
    val data = list[position]
    holder.spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            holder.spinner.setSelection(1)
        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            val text:Int = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position) as Int
            holder.spinner.setSelection(text)
        }

    }
    holder.name.text = data.itemName
    holder.price.text = holder.spinner.onItemSelectedListener.toString()
```

This is the createviewholder function where I have used spinner.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): View_Holder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false)
        res_name.text = "Ordering From "+list[0].itemRes
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            context,
            R.array.quantity,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        )
        val spinner = view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        spinner.adapter = adapter

                return View_Holder(view)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a reference from following code it will help

```
override fun onItemSelected(arg0:AdapterView<*>, arg1:View, position: Int, id:Long) {
    val text:String = arg0?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
    //you should update view from here 
    holder.name.text = data.itemName
    holder.price.text = "₹ " + data.itemPrice + "/-"
}
```

Comment: When I did that, I'm getting an error " null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.String"  @DharmenderManral

Comment: try to update view inside onItemSelected, it will be better approach

Comment: @yazhini add spinner inside view holder class. Now in the `onBindViewHolder` method, you can get access to your `holder.spinner.onItemSelectedListener` complete your Item select code here

Comment: I updated me OnBindViewHolder. I still get the same error "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference"

Comment: correct this line inside onBindViewHolder , it should be   holder.price.text = holder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()

Comment: Still the same error is shown. I have updated both the functions here. @DharmenderManral

Comment: you are doing in wrong way  ideally you should do all thing inside holder class. Can you post me on my mail dharmender.manral@gmail.com